# How to find white bordered rectangle in an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I'm trying to get the coordinate of the white-bordered rectangle in image. The traditional approach is to find contours to find all the rectangles present in the image but I want to get only with certain bordered color like in the below picture [image]

How can I get the coordinates of white bordered rectangle only using opencv?
any suggestions on this very helpful, thanks

Edit: I tried suggestion given by guivi using python as below

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random as rng
image = cv2.imread('strawberry.png')
threshold = 100
grayscale= cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny_output = cv2.Canny(grayscale, threshold, threshold * 2)

ret, thresh= cv2.threshold(grayscale,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(canny_output,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours_poly = [None]*len(contours)
#boundRect = [None]*len(contours)
boundRect = list()
centers = [None]*len(contours)
radius = [None]*len(contours)
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    contours_poly[i] = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
    if len(contours_poly[i]) == 4:
        boundRect.append(cv2.boundingRect(contours_poly[i]))
    #boundRect[i] = cv.boundingRect(contours_poly[i])
    #centers[i], radius[i] = cv.minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i])


drawing = np.zeros((canny_output.shape[0], canny_output.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)

print(len(boundRect))
#for i in range(len(contours)):
#    color = (rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256))
#    cv.drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, color)
#    cv.rectangle(drawing, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
#      (int(boundRect[i][0]+boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1]+boundRect[i][3])), color, 2)
#cv.circle(drawing, (int(centers[i][0]), int(centers[i][1])), int(radius[i]), color, 2)
for i in range(len(boundRect)):
    if boundRect[i][2]/boundRect[i][3] > 2:
        color = (rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256))
        cv2.rectangle(drawing, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
            (int(boundRect[i][0]+boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1]+boundRect[i][3])), color, 2)
        print(f'Rectangle X:{boundRect[i][0]}, Y:{boundRect[i][1]}, W:{boundRect[i][2]}, H:{boundRect[i][3]}')
```

but I couldn't find position of rectangle in image as @guivi got using c++ instead I got the some other 4 rectangle coordinates as shown below image
[image: img_op]

Answer (score 0):

You can do as you are thinking more or less:

1. load the image.
2. convert to gray scale.
3. apply some threshold.
4. Calculate the contours.
5. Look at the contours and check for shapes.
6. segregate rectangles and filter by aspect ratio.
7. you are done!

I used C++ to achieve this but I am sure you can convert it to python.

```
Mat image = imread("st.bmp");

if (image.empty())
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(image, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
vector<vector<Point>> contoursgray;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchygray;
threshold(gray, gray, 200, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
findContours(gray, contoursgray, hierarchygray, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
// draw contours on the original image
Mat image_contour_gray = image.clone();
//drawContours( image_contour_gray, contoursgray, -1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
vector<vector<Point>> contoursgray2;
for (auto points : contoursgray) {
    double peri = cv::arcLength(points, true);
    vector<Point> aprox;
    cv::approxPolyDP(points, aprox, 0.04 * peri, true);
    if (aprox.size() == 4)
    {
        cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(aprox);
        if (rect.width / rect.height > 1.5) {
            std::cout << rect.x << "  " << rect.y << " " << rect.width << " " << rect.height << std::endl;
            contoursgray2.push_back(aprox);                
        }
    }
}
if (contoursgray2.size() > 0) {
    drawContours(image_contour_gray, contoursgray2, -1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    imshow("Contour detection using gray conversion", image_contour_gray);
}
waitKey(0);
imwrite("gray.jpg", image_contour_gray);
destroyAllWindows();
```

This gives me the following image as output:
[image: outputimage:]

And it also outputs the following rectangles(x, y, w, h) on the command prom:

[image]

I have taken the tutorial from [opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html) webpage and changed the following lines:

```
contours_poly = [None]*len(contours)
#boundRect = [None]*len(contours)
boundRect = list()
centers = [None]*len(contours)
radius = [None]*len(contours)
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    contours_poly[i] = cv.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
    if len(contours_poly[i]) == 4:
        boundRect.append(cv.boundingRect(contours_poly[i]))
    #boundRect[i] = cv.boundingRect(contours_poly[i])
    #centers[i], radius[i] = cv.minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i])


drawing = np.zeros((canny_output.shape[0], canny_output.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)


#for i in range(len(contours)):
#    color = (rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256))
#    cv.drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, color)
#    cv.rectangle(drawing, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
#      (int(boundRect[i][0]+boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1]+boundRect[i][3])), color, 2)
#cv.circle(drawing, (int(centers[i][0]), int(centers[i][1])), int(radius[i]), color, 2)
for i in range(len(boundRect)):
    if boundRect[i][2]/boundRect[i][3] > 2:
        color = (rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256))
        cv.rectangle(drawing, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
            (int(boundRect[i][0]+boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1]+boundRect[i][3])), color, 2)
        print(f'Rectangle X:{boundRect[i][0]}, Y:{boundRect[i][1]}, W:{boundRect[i][2]}, H:{boundRect[i][3]}')
```

Comment: hey I tried to convert your c++ code in python I ended up getting error please check the updated question for the code, let me know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @xionxavier OpenCV tutorial webpage has your answer. Look at this page:
[https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html)
If you run this with your image you will get an idea of how the functions work. The different version of OpenCV seems to use this functions slightly differently so make sure you look at the right version of the page based on the version of OpenCV you are using.

Comment: I followed that tutorial and tried to implement but I wasn't able to get the coordinates of rectangle please check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/69206088/16707127

Comment: @xionxavier The example above displays the coordinates of the rectangle's corners. Are you not getting the same results, or did you expect something different? Please clarify exactly *what* is not working for you rather than opening a new question.

Comment: I'm not able to find coordinates of rectangle using python program, I'm not knowledgeable in c++ so I'm having difficulties to convert it into python

Comment: @xionxavier In the tutorial there is the use of approxPolyDP which I am also using in the example I showed you above in C++ (python is just the same, look at the tutorial).
After using the approxPolyDP you can then check for polygons that have 4 points to approximate the boundingRect. Then you can use the aspect ratio of this to filter the specific rectangle you are interested on.

Comment: @xionxavier I have updated my answer above. I have basically changed the tutorial python code.

Comment: @xionxavier Also I have tested your last code and the problem is you have to change the line:  
`cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`  
to  
`cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`

Comment: @guivi hey thanks for the code example I tried it but I wasn't able to find any boundingRect for the same image. Did you check for the same image? I've included my edited code in the question

Comment: @xionxavier You have to remove the threshold and cv.Canny already returns an image you can use in cv2.findContours

Comment: @guivi ok I used cv.Canny with threshold value of 100 I ended up getting some rectangle which I'm not interested at. I can see canny image showing rectangle of interested but find contours not able to detect it. What am I doing wrong ?check updated question

Comment: @xionxavier if you run this as per the tutorial page on opnencv the program will have a slider which you can use to control the threshold. Try that. I think at this point it is just a matter for you to play with that threshold and see what you can do. Play around and try to understand what is happening. Also try swapping the canny function with a threshold only one. Good luck. You are pretty much there.